# The relation between semidirect products and HNN extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I am currently trying to solve an exercise that consists of two parts:

1. Let $H$ be a group and $A \leq H$ be a subgroup such that there is an injection $\phi: A \rightarrow H$. Let $G$ be the HNN-extension of $H$ by $\phi$. 
   Let further $F = \langle \star_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} H_i | a_{i+1} = \phi(a)_i \rangle $ such that every $H_i$ is a copy of $H$ and $h \mapsto h_i$ identifies $H$ with $H_i \subseteq F$. 
   Show that $G$ is isomorphic to a semidirect product of $F$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.
2. Show that the HNN extension obtained through the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 3\mathbb{Z}$ can be described as a semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}$ and a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$.

I have no idea for the first case and in the second case, I see that the presentation of the HNN extension should be $\langle a, t | t^{-1}at = a^3\rangle$ and this looks very similar to the presentation of a semidirect product, but I don't find the right homomorphism and the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Here are some hints. In the first part $H_i = H^{t^i}$, where $t$ is the added generator in the HNN extension $G$, and $F$ is the normal closure of $H$ in $G$. In the second part, the subgroup of ${\mathbb Q}$ that you are looking for is $\{ a3^{k} : a,k \in {\mathbb Z}\}$.

Comment: $\phi$ is part of the data, not only the assumption of its existence. So you shouldn't write "such that there is an injection $\phi$..." but "and $\phi$ an injective homomorphism..."